# Apple Mach-O Linker(Id) Error -swift

Tags: ios, xcode

This question has been asked but with different error references and different from what i am encountering
working with Xcode and i get :

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_mirrorTunnelProvider",referenced from:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_mirrorConfig",referenced from:
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_mirrorPacketTunnelProvider",referenced from:
Linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)
```

This app Builds and installs fine on a phone with ios version 10.1.1 but Fails to build with the above error on a phone with ios version 9.3.4.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have that iOS version(9.3.4) installed on your simulator?

Comment: i have two separate phones. will clarify

Comment: Sorry..thought you used simulator